# Actionscript function definition

Tags: actionscript-3

How can I define functions that can receive unknown/variable amount of parameters?

Answer (score 7):

It is called rest parameter, Use this:

```
function getItems(...rest):void
{
    // ... logic goes here
}
```

Inside the function you deal with rest as the name of the array.

When creating a rest parameter you should keep these in mind:

- Rest parameters are untyped. It is up to you to validate any special type requirements as you loop through the rest parameter array.
- Rest parameters must be at the end of a method's parameters.
- The rest parameters must have ... in front of it, but the variable name can be anything.

Answer (score 4):

```
private function someFunction(...args) : void
{
  for(var i : int = 0; i < args.length ; i++)
  {
     trace(i, args[i]);
  }
}
```